# Where is aws cloudwatch Logs state_file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to set up aws cloudwatch log service on my linux instance. In the config file they say to put something like this:

```
[general]
state_file = <value>
logging_config_file = <value>
use_gzip_http_content_encoding = [true | false]
```

Where state_file [Specifies where the state file is stored](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) according to the docs. I don't see any mention of this state_file anywhere else. Can anyone help me figure out what this file is and where I might be able to find it? I downloaded the logs using `yum install -y awslogs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is where AWS logs keeps its current state, i.e. how it knows what log messages it has already sent. To find it, you need to look at the `state_file` location configured in your `/etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf` file, and then look there.

Looking on one of my servers it appears the default state file location was `/var/lib/awslogs/agent-state`. Looking at that file it appears to be a SQLite database file.

Comment: I think state_file can be put anywhere, so you specify it in awslogs.conf and awslogsd will put it there

Comment: @maslick that's what I said in my first paragraph...